# ostream on a std::unique_ptr class member

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

I would like to print a std::unique_ptr which is a class member of Bar.
However, the following code does not work see my comment on *stream << bar.foo_unique();*
I think I should change my foo_unique() accessor but I don't know how.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <memory>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : n_(1) {}
    int n() const { return n_; }

private:
    int n_;
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Foo& foo);

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Foo& foo)
{
    stream << foo.n();
    return stream;
}

class Bar 
{
public:
    Bar() : m_(2), foo_(), foo_unique_(std::make_unique<Foo>()) {}
    int m() const { return m_; }
    const Foo& foo() const { return foo_; }
    const std::unique_ptr<Foo>& foo_unique() const { return foo_unique_; }   // what to return here ?
private:
    int m_;
    Foo foo_;                         
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_unique_;  
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Bar& bar);

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Bar& bar)
{
    stream << bar.m() << ",";
    stream << bar.foo();
    // stream << bar.foo_unique(); // does not work !!!
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    std::cout << bar << std::endl;
}
```

How can I do that properly ?

edit : I want stream << bar.foo_unique(); to have the same behaviour as stream << bar.foo();

Comment: For a 341 reputation it is not good that you provide an error description like that!

Comment: 1) What is `const std::unique_ptr<Foo>& foo_unique() const` supposed to do (precisely)? Why is it necessary in addition to `Foo const& foo() const`? 2) What is `stream << bar.foo_unique();` supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision stream << bar.foo_unique(); should have the same behaviour as stream << bar.foo(); !

Comment: If you write `stream << *bar.foo_unique();`, you'll get the exact same behaviour. If you don't want to have to write that extra `*`, you'll need to define another `operator<<`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no output operator defined for `std::unique_ptr<T>`: it is a bit sad but many of the C++ classes are lacking output operators. The easiest approach is to just print the pointer:

```
stream << bar.foo_unique().get();
```

if you want to get the actually pointer printed or you'd dereference the pointer

```
stream << *bar.foo_unique();
```

if you want to get the pointee printed.

To use the output operator you can create your own output operator taking a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` assuming `Foo` is a user-defined type. You'd put it into the same namespace as where `Foo` is defined:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, std::unique_ptr<Foo> const& foo) {
    return out << *foo; // or foo.get()depending on what you want to get printed
}
```

Comment: Thank you _stream << *bar.foo_unique();_ works the way wanted. However, adding your last code gives me _error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::ostream&_

Comment: He forgot `out <<`. The return statement should read: `return out << *foo;`

Comment: @leemes: true - the peril of not testing code! Thanks for fixing!

Comment: "*There is no output operator defined for `std::unique_ptr<T>`*" - [C++20 adds one now](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_ltlt).

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit conversion from `std::unique_ptr<T>` to `T const&` which is preventing the stream insertion operator from being determined. You have a couple of options here though. The first option is to provide one override of `operator<<` for `std::unique_ptr<T>` and one for `T&`. This can get tedious if you have use both `std::unique_ptr` and non-owning raw pointers or references. The second option is to provide a single templated version of `operator<<` to handle instances of `std::unique_ptr<T>` and then individual ones to handle `T const&`. Below is an example of how to accomplish this.

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, Foo const& arg)
{
    // output stuff here
    return out;
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, std::unique_ptr<T> const& arg)
{
    return out << *arg;
}
```

Comment: *"which is preventing the stream insertion operator from being deduced"* Deduced as in *template argument deduction*?